# Microsoft Word VBA Wildcard String

Tags: vba, ms-word, wildcard, boolean-logic

long story short I'm using a script that highlights words that use a certain format and then exporting them to excel. I can't seem to use Word's built in wildcard system to get the results I'm looking for (I'm not very familiar with it), but I am close!

I'm looking to extract definitions that fall in a certain format inline:

This is the sample text (the "sample") for you ("helpful person" or "HP") to use, this "should be" possible.

My string should capture sample, helpful person, and HP above (but not "should be"). Which is to say all text in quotes between parenthesis.

Currently I can manage to pull everything between smart or straight quotes with this:

```
    (" & ChrW(8220) & ")(*)(" & ChrW(8221) & ")
```

[the char numbers are for angled quotes]

This of course returns strings that are in quotes even without those quotes being nested in parenthesis.

Can anyone get me on the right track? Thanks so much!

Note that the rest of the script is using MSwords wildcard system, *not* regex, so changing to regex is out :(.

The full script here just highlights the words that match the string:

```
Sub findfunction()
  If (findHL(ActiveDocument.Content, "(" & ChrW(8220) & ")(*)(" & ChrW(8221) & ")")) = True Then _
     MsgBox "Done", vbInformation + vbOKOnly, "Result"
End Sub

Function findHL(r As Range, s As String) As Boolean
  Options.DefaultHighlightColorIndex = wdYellow
  r.Find.Replacement.Highlight = True
  r.Find.Execute FindText:=s, MatchWildcards:=True, _
                 Wrap:=wdFindContinue, Format:=True, _
                 replacewith:="", Replace:=wdReplaceAll
  findHL = True
End Function
```

Thanks again.

Comment: So you have a macro you're running in Word?  You should share the code so we can understand what you're really doing.

Comment: Excellent point. Adding it to the OP now.

Comment: Everything works, I get the highlights and later the exports I want. The only problem I'm having is writing the wildcard string to capture all words within quotes that are within parentheses. So far I can return everything in quotes, or I can return everything within parenthesis, but not both!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works for me. But I don't believe it can be done with a "simple" Find/Replace. What I had to do was locate each instance, then "walk" the range backwards to see if I can find an opening parenthesis, then forwards to find a closing parenthesis - always checking that no intervening closing resp. opening parenthesis is present. Only then can the highlighting be applied.

In order to do this, three separate Range objects are required: one for the search, one for the found range and one to test going backwards/forwards.

```
Sub findfunction()
  If (findHL(ActiveDocument.content, _
      "(" & ChrW(8220) & ")(*)(" & ChrW(8221) & ")")) = True Then
     MsgBox "Done", vbInformation + vbOKOnly, "Result"
  End If
End Sub

Function findHL(r As Range, s As String) As Boolean
    Dim success As Boolean
    Dim foundRange As word.Range
    Dim testRange As word.Range
    Dim moved As Long

  success = False
  Set foundRange = r.Duplicate
  Options.DefaultHighlightColorIndex = wdYellow
  r.Find.Replacement.Highlight = True
  Do
    success = foundRange.Find.Execute(findText:=s, MatchWildcards:=True, _
                 wrap:=wdFindStop, Format:=True)
    If success Then
        r.Start = foundRange.End
        Set testRange = foundRange.Duplicate
        moved = testRange.MoveStartUntil("()", wdBackward)
        If moved < 0 Then
            testRange.MoveStart wdCharacter, -1
            If Left(testRange, 1) = "(" Then
                moved = testRange.MoveEndUntil(")", wdForward)
                If moved > 0 Then
                    testRange.MoveEnd wdCharacter, 1
                    If Right(testRange, 1) = ")" Then
                      foundRange.HighlightColorIndex = wdYellow
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If
  Loop While success = True
  findHL = True
End Function
```

Comment: OUTSTANDING. Thank you so much! Since it's now clear that you are absurdly awesome at this. Would it be possible to only do it up to a certain page number somehow? Specifically after some point page numbers change from 1,2,3, to F-1, F-2, F-3; Is there a way I can program it to ignore those? 

Either way you are absolutely amazing and just made my day!

Comment: I take it the page numbering changes with Section Breaks? So you could test which section the Range is in?

Comment: Theoretically it would, but I plan on using this on many different documents with different numbers of sections between them, in a different order, titled differently etc, but only for sure thing I know after the pages switch to F-#, I'm not interested in reviewing them haha. 

I can't thank you enough for your help! It's amazing! I have a follow up question but at this point I feel like I'm taking advantage!

Comment: Come to think of it, forget the page numbers - I can manually just take care of that. If you had 5 minutes to help me craft one that highlights words that are capitalized but are not the first word of a sentence and highlight those, that would be amazing (as in forgetting about the quotes and parenthesis, just a new question). Can't thank you enough, you've been so helpful!

Comment: Well, don't forget to mark "the answer" before you ask your new question :-) But remember this is StackOverflow - it's not a free coding service. Writing code is actually what I get paid for... And it usually takes longer than five minutes!

Comment: So now I have a different problem: Your fantastic code indeed highlights my content according to the rule. Later I use a different code to export that content into Excel, which seems to no longer pull the highlights made by the new code. I'm not very experienced with VBA or Word, but does your code highlight things 'differently" than mine did? 

Provide me some contact info as well, I have many little projects like this I'd be happy to hire someone to help with.

Comment: I don't think  my code highlights any differently than yours did.. but at 11 pm local time I can't do any investigating. You can find my contact information in my mvp profile: https://mvp.microsoft.com/en-us/PublicProfile/7287?fullName=Cindy%20%20Meister

Answer (score 0):

Maybe run your function twice in your sub:

```
Sub findfunction()
  found = False
  If findHL(ActiveDocument.Content, [wildcard string for condition A]) = True Then found = True
  If findHL(ActiveDocument.Content, [wildcard string for condition B]) = True Then found = True
  If found = True Then MsgBox "Done", vbInformation + vbOKOnly, "Result"
End Sub
```

I don't see how any of this exports to Excel though

Comment: Hmm that's a clever approach! I can't seem to format it in a way that doesn't throw errors. I'm not a regex expert and I'm certainly not a word advanced search expert but it seems like this should be possible just in one string!. Setting a variable for true and then highlighting words with both true would work too I'm sure, but probably sends me down the road towards further syntax problems as this is definitely not my arena. 

Mostly just wanted to say thanks for your contribution. I'd be so stoked to get this working!

Comment: It may be possible in a single command but it's harder to isolate issue when you attempt to accomplish more than one thing per step.

Comment: For sure, I'm open to whatever actually gets the result. I just don't know how to begin making your suggestion actually work in practice, though I concede it's a great approach. Maybe someone can come along and help me turn that into syntactically solid code.

Thanks again for your help!

Comment: When you said "So far I can return everything in quotes, or I can return everything within parenthesis, but not both!" I assumed that you could apply the two strings that yielded this comment.